# When I deploy a node.js app to Elastic Bean Environment

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, deployment, ebcli

When I make the deploy via EB CLI. Everything goes smoothly. But when I open my link. It doesn´t show content. I have tried to move the .ebextensions and the server.js to accomodate the static files. But I havent been able to resolve it.

[Here is the eb log of 'access'](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RVyH7.png)

[Terminal Log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hG2nG.png)

[Link on browser](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dpVKx.png)

Comment: Have you checked the output of `eb log`? There might be an indication there as to what's wrong.

Comment: I have. There is no indication of error

Comment: This is a difficult one to address. Typically, the "access" section of the logs convey something useful. Does the application work locally?

Comment: In my question there is a screenshot of the 'access log'

Comment: I can't tell what the problem is.